# I saw him play/ playing

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verb-agreement

Which one is correct? What is the main differences between them?

I saw him play football 
Or
I saw him playing

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, this topic has been done to death here, and possibly even on English Language Learners.

Comment: Use the search box. Present progressive.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular sentence, the most common sentence by far would be

> I saw him playing football

This means that I saw him, and what he was doing at the time, was *playing football*.

Let's take a different example: *perform* vs. *performing*.

1. I'm a big fan of Marcel Marceau's.  I've watched everything of his I can find on Youtube.  I even saw him perform once, live, about 40 years ago.  I'll never forget it.
2. I saw my son playing with our little neighbor this afternoon.  It looked like they were having a great time.

The key difference is the "once" in Example 1.