# I watched her become a mother vs I watched her becoming a mother

Tags: grammar

Which one has more correct way to put, and what are the differences found on those two sentences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I saw him crossing" vs. "I saw him cross"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/i-saw-him-crossing-vs-i-saw-him-cross)

Comment: [Another similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509936/i-saw-him-play-playing/509939#509939/)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yeah, i think it’s very, relatively relevant answer for sure. Except i don’t know how to interpret the 2nd example sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. There is a (rather insignificant, though) difference in meaning.

*I watched her become a mother* = *I remember her from before pregnancy, and I can see how she's different now*. (The emphasis is on the difference).

*I watched her becoming a mother* = *I remember the process of her changing from day to day*. (The emphasis is on the transformation process).

See: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing

Comment: 

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the first phrase is more correct as 'becoming' is more appropriate in the present rather than the past, with 'watched' being past tense. It'd be better if the tense and wording of the second phrase was changed so it would say 'She is becoming a mother.' But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: Thanks charli. That’s originally what came across my mind as well. So would probably be correct to say ‘I watched her to become a mother’ rather than the original sentence that i wrote for question ‘I watched her become a mom’?

Comment: @Mark There is no construction of the verb "to watch" with "to" and "infinitive"; "to become"  would not make a verbal unit with "watch" but would be the verb of the infinitive clause "to become a mother", and that clause would be an adverbial; notice that there is no adverbial in the sentence without "to". What you'd be saying in fact, if "to" were added would be quite different; it would be something like this: "I watched her so that I would  learn how to become  a mother.".